# Insalling Windows 10 on a laptop with 32GB space

Tags: usb, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, oem

I'm currently trying to install Windows 10 on my laptop with 32GB eMMC.

I tried letting it download the upgrade files, but it will take forever. I'm assuming that my laptop has not enough space, since my laptop is full before the downloading finished.

I also tried burning the ISO to an USB using the MediaCreationTool, but running the setup.exe in Windows does not work. The error, "Setup failed to initialize the working directory", appeared.

After reading other articles, I am currently thinking of booting my laptop up with the USB and upgrade from there. However, some people are saying that even if you choose the upgrade option from the USB, it will prompt for a product key instead of registering your hardware for Windows 10.

An article says that you can skip the product key part and it will register itself after installation. It also tells me to dig up my OEM product key just in case.

Will I be successful doing that?

I am also worried about not being able to upgrade to Windows 10, and I would have difficulty reinstalling Windows 8.1 with my OEM key.

Comment: You're eligible for the upgrade as long as you start setup from within Windows. It doesn't matter where/how. Just don't do a clean install by accident by booting off the USB drive.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a [2 USB drives](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/The-Defrag-Show/Defrag-Lots-of-Windows-10-Stick-PCs-PST-tips-Zombie-Libraries-and-more#time=0m36s). Install the Windows 10 Media to the 1 USB stick and leave the second empty. During setup Windows 10 will tell that you don't have enough free space and will allow to use the 2nd (empty) USB drive for storing temporary files.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, when I tried to run the setup.exe on the usb, it says failed 'failed to initialize the working directory'

Comment: you still have not enough free memory on C:\ https://sysadminspot.com/windows/windows-10-error-setup-has-failed-to-initialize-the-working-directory/